# Is there a way to call another website's HTML form's submit action with php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically get the search results from
http://pokemonshowdown.com/replay/

```
    <form action="/replay/search/" method="get" data-target="replace">
        <p style="text-align:center">
            <label><input type="text" name="user" class="textbox" placeholder="Format or username" size="24" /></label>
            <button type="submit"><strong>Search</strong></button>
        </p>
    </form>
```

but I don't know how to trigger the onsubmit action of the form using code, only by clicking on it X_X

I plan on getting the search results and using them to automatically cycle through replays so I don't have to keep clicking on them to watch.

Comment: so, you have a site www.siteX.com, and you want to submit a form and load the result from www.siteY.com, and then do something with the data on siteX ?

Comment: Yes, basically I would want to create a site or a browser plugin to look at the search results, parse them, then pick a replay and display it. I am currently stuck at getting the search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right you want to initiate a search on an exterior site? Because it is a get-form it should be easily done by requesting the URL "http://pokemonshowdown.com/replay/search/?key=value". You do not have to really submit the form, just call the URL the form would call in case of an onclick-event.

Of course key and value have to be replaced by the field name and the value you want to insert. Multiple parameters would be concatenated, like key1=value1&key2=value2.